# Hide rows in google sheets using python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I would like to hide rows in a document using python, to authomatize a project, but I tried with spread and there is no option.

So I would like to know if there's any possibility to do it using python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to hide the rows of a sheet in Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Sheets API with gspread of python.
- You have already been able to use Sheets API and gspread.

In this case, I think that your goal can be achieved using [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest) with the method of [`batch_update`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update). When this is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials) # Please use your authorization script for this.
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheetId = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName).id
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateDimensionProperties": {
                "properties": {
                    "hiddenByUser": True
                },
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "dimension": "ROWS",
                    "startIndex": 1,
                    "endIndex": 10
                },
                "fields": "hiddenByUser"
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

- When above script is run, the rows 2 to 10 of "Sheet1" in Google Spreadsheet `spreadsheetId` are hidden.

#### Note:

- This sample script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API with gspread. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest)

Comment: @eljequercin Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: What would be the best way to hide rows that do not follow each other, for example `['1,5,6,8,16,42,64]`?

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis bout your question of `What would be the best way to hide rows that do not follow each other, for example ['1,5,6,8,16,42,64]?`, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. So in order to correctly understand your question, can you post it as new question? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?